# Is there anyway to install Tensorflow on Windows from source

Tags: windows, tensorflow

My company's firewall blocks the usage of pip/conda install. Is there anyway to install Tensorflow on Windows the same way we do for Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a pip package from the cmakefile by following the instructions in [tensorflow/contrib/cmake/README.md](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/cmake/README.md).